# IF sempre me dá a mesma resposta!

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x, bebida;

    cout<<"Digite 'bebida' "<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    if(x == bebida){
        cout<<"Esta certo"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        (x != bebida);
        cout<<"Esta errado"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O retorno que quero obter é o seguinte, caso eu entre com "bebida" o `if` me   volta com "Esta certo" do contrário "Esta errado".

O que ocorre é que independente do que eu escreva, ele sempre me retorna com "Esta Certo".

Comment: qual o retorno? o que você espera?

Comment: você não inicializa a variável "bebida", logo era sempre será 0, é isso que você quer?

Comment: O retorno que quero obter é o seguinte, Caso eu entre com "bebida" o if me   volta com "Esta certo" do contrário "Esta errado".
O que ocorre é que independente do que eu escreva, ele sempre me retorna com "Esta Certo".

Comment: @Math em c++ não é lixo de memória o valor da variável não inicializada?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não lembro bem a teoria, mas fiz um teste e foi esse o resultado: https://ideone.com/pRqk34

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você criou uma variável com o nome "bebida" quando na verdade você deveria usar uma string literal, se deseja comparar uma variável com uma string essa variável também deve ser do tipo `string`, portanto mude a declaração do seu `x` para `string` e elimine a variável `bebida`.

Além disso dentro do seu `else` tem uma tentativa de comparação estilo `else if` que é desnecessária, então pode simplesmente pode ser retirada.

Resumindo tudo, fica assim:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string x;

    cout<<"Digite 'bebida' "<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    if(x == "bebida"){
        cout<<"Esta certo"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Esta errado"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/C9xmWB)

Quando você diz :

> O que ocorre é que independente do que eu escreva, ele sempre me retorna com "Esta Certo".

É por que no seu código original você declarou `x` e `bebida` como inteiros, a variável `bebida` você nunca inicializava, logo ela assumia o valor de `0`, já para a variável `x` você escrevia uma string, então ela também ficava com valor de `0` e a comparação das duas variáveis retornava true.

Comment: Obrigado galera!

Answer (score 1):

Que tal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string x;

    cout << "Digite 'bebida' " << endl;

    cin >> x;

    if( x == "bebida" ) {
        cout<<"Esta certo"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Esta errado" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nossa é exatamente isso que eu queria fazer!
Amigo(a) você poderia me explicar a solução?